# SVG lag in iOS 5.1 vs. @2x PNG

Tags: ios, webkit, svg, png, retina-display

I have a SVG sprite I am loading into both my regular and mobile sites. The SVG is 74kb.
When loaded in the normal site on a New iPad(v3) iOS 5.1(9B176) there are zero scrolling and zooming issues whatsoever. There a 24 instances where a portion of the sprite is displayed.

When I load the same SVG into the mobile site on a iPhone 4 iOS 5.1(9B176) I get a significant lag in scrolling up and down when I lift my finger. If I leave my finger on the screen there are no scroll issues. Ther are only 16 instances where a portion of the sprite is displayed. If I replace the SVG with a @2x PNG (152kb) I have no scrolling issues. On the mobile site there is no zooming, since the viewport is set to user-scalable=0.

I was wondering what the issue could be and why this might be happening. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: 74kb is pretty large for an SVG. It just might be extremely complicated.

Comment: Thanks @GlennHowes. Since this post I have managed to make a significant number of updates. This is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I add CSS transform or blackface-visibility it starts to flicker and lag  at the end of zooming/scrolling when it redraws. So try to remove any CSS animation you have on the page and see if it has any impact.